# API key for Mailchimp API authentication Methods

Tags: oauth-2.0, mailchimp

We are exploring the **MailChimp API v3.0**. There are two types of authentication methods: Basic and OAuth 2.

We are able to authenticate using both ways, but there is confusion with the Authorization Header part:

1. Basic Authentication (both authorization headers below work):

   - Authorization: Basic base64 format of `username:APIkey`
   - Authorization: Basic only APIKey
2. OAuth 2 Authentication (both authorization headers below work):

   - Authorization: OAuth access_token
   - Authorization: OAuth only APIKey

The API documentation refers only to the first approach of each of the above authentication methods.

Is the second approach of each valid? i.e. can we authenticate using only the API key in the place of the base64 encoded string (Basic auth), and only the API key in place of the access token (OAuth 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth on MailChimp is a way to retrieve an access token. You can then use that access token (or an API Key that you get from the dashboard) in the Basic Auth setup.

While it may work to pass the API key by itself in the header, I'd recommend following the actual Basic Auth methodology of the base64 encoded 'username:apikey' or 'username:access_token'. Almost all HTTP libraries will do this part for you. For example, with cURL, you can do this:

```
curl --user myusername:myapikey "https://dev.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/"
```

Depending on your language and library, it will be handled different ways, but all of the ones I've worked with have made it easy to do Basic Auth.